# How does PayPal receive the price of an item via "Pay with PayPal"?

Tags: paypal

The question may sound dumb, but I'm having difficulties understanding how "Pay with PayPal" functionality works in terms of the architecture. Specifically, how does PayPal receive the price from the checkout page when "Pay with PayPal" button is clicked? Would appreciate if someone could explain how is the architecture modeled and how does it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A specific answer to this question depends entirely on the integration method used to implement the 'Pay with PayPal' button. But almost invariably, there is an `amount` or `amt` field.

For a specific example, here is an integration method that uses client-side HTML/JavaScript only (no server-side API calls): https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

---

The same front-end can be paired with server-side APIs, if desired -- note the fetch calls to '/demo/...' placeholder routes in the following example, which must be replaced with actual routes on a server that reate a v2/order and return an OrderID, and then capture that v2/order, respectively: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

---

Older/classic/deprecated integration methods are available, so as mentioned, the specifics of how the price is transferred will depend on the integration method used.

Comment: Thanks, the answer is pretty close to what I was looking for. So does that mean that as a merchant on my website I have to have a function that passes the generated total amount of the order to the `amount` field instead of hardcoding it?